# Linux for multiple, independent slide shows for theatre productions?

Tags: linux, microsoft-powerpoint

I just finished up a production of The Elephant Man where we used three laptops running Power Point that fed three different projectors, with three different slide shows, all controlled by one person. Question:

Is is it possible/viable to run a linux box that controls multiple video cards that feed multiple projectors with separate slide shows with the projection operator controlling slide advance from one monitor with independent instances of whatever slide show software that is available.  I know nada about Linux/Unix.  Any help is appreciated......cause there has to be a better way than I went.

MWA

Comment: As there are graphic cards that support multiple displays, I say it is possible. As for viability... maybe you will run into the same problems you had in your previous setup (it isn't easy to support 3 presentations at one time, as a single person).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether you need each of the presentations to advance to the next slide simultaneously, from one cue or whether each gets individual cues at different times.

If simultaneously, the solution's pretty simple; some wireless remotes (some Interlink models, I think?) allow you to set multiple units to listen to the same "clicker".  This'd work with any system, Linux/Windows/Mac/Whatever, that can accept clicks from a USB mouse to advance slides.

Alternatively, there's a Windows PPT add-in/companion app called PowerShow, I believe, that lets you run and independently control multiple PPT shows from one PC, feeding multiple monitors. http://officeone.mvps.org is the URL, as I recall.  Not a linux solution, obviously, but it might help.